# FileObserver not working with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent, fileobserver

I need to use camera intent and keep track of the new images taken by the intent. As I need to take multiple photos at a time, I used the intent `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`. Here is my code:

```
package com.arko.cameraintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class CameraMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQ_CODE = 0;
    AppCompatActivity main_activity = this;  // save it for future use
    DirectoryFileObserver directoryFileObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_main);

    }

    public void takePhoto(View view)  // fired when a button in the main application is clicked. This starts the camera application.
    {

        Intent callCamAppIntent = new Intent();
        callCamAppIntent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
        String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(this, dir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        directoryFileObserver = new DirectoryFileObserver(dir);
        directoryFileObserver.startWatching();
        startActivityForResult(callCamAppIntent, REQ_CODE);


    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
            Toast.makeText(this, "picture taken successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            directoryFileObserver.stopWatching();
        }
    }

}
```

The code of `DirectoryFileObserver` class:

```
package com.arko.cameraintent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.File;


public class DirectoryFileObserver extends FileObserver {
    String rootDir;
    static final int mask = (FileObserver.CREATE | FileObserver.MODIFY | FileObserver.DELETE);
    public final String DIRECTORY_NAME = "Simplified Intent";

    public DirectoryFileObserver(String path) {

        super(path, mask);
        rootDir = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
        switch(event){
            case FileObserver.CREATE:
                String outputDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES +
                        File.separator + DIRECTORY_NAME;

                // do something here
                break;

            case FileObserver.MODIFY:
                // will be implemented later
                break;
            case FileObserver.DELETE:
                // will be implemented later
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

But the `onEvent` function never gets executed, as suggested by Debug. What is the reason behind it? I have even changed the default save location of the camera application to Internal Storage (initially it was set to SD card) and ran my app again, but nothing changed. I have mentioned both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: Please note that there is no requirement for the user's chosen camera app to store its photos in the directory that you are monitoring.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, but my default camera app is storing the photos in the DCIM directory, and I have used that directory. Shouldn't it still work now?

Comment: If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need to set up runtime permissions.

Comment: I have mentioned both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in the manifest file. What is the "run-time permission"? @CommonsWare

Comment: [Runtime permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it) were added over two years ago, in Android 6.0. This should be covered in any up-to-date book on Android app development, in addition to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).